# Achieve Aspect Fill behaviour when loading image base64 into UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, uiimageview, uiimage, base64, nsdata

I have a UIWebView the loads an image encoded in base64.

```
[webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:contentType textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

imageData is an NSData object.

I want the UIWebView to show the image the same way an ImageView would show the image using the Aspect Fill content mode.
Since it's a UIWebView I would still like to be able to pan the image around and zoomin/zoomout.